# Fetch a single column from Realm Database (Android)

Tags: android, database, realm

I'm a beginner in Realm.

I have a table with 3 columns which named *Id, Name, Email,Address*.
To get the data of Name column, we use a query like **'SELECT Name from table_name'**  for SQLite.

If we using Realm in Android, then which method do we have to use for fetching the data of only one column?

I searched alot on Google & documentation but to no avail.
Could anyone help me?

**Update:**

What I am tried:

```
RealmResults<User> results = query.findAll();
ArrayList<String> name = new Arraylist(); 
for(i=0; i<results.size; i++){ 
 name.add(result.get(i).getName();
}
```

**My problem:**

```
results.size()  > 10k. So I want to avoid 10k iteration

for(i=0; i<results.size; i++){ 
}
```

Comment: Downvoter pls mention the reason for downvoting.. Anything wrong in my question? before downvoting you must experienced person in realm.

Comment: You have to first fetch all data from database like `RealmResults<User> result1 = query.findAll();` and secondly use for loop to get column _name_ in a different arraylist. For eg.
`ArrayList<String> name = new Arraylist();
for(i=0; i<result1.size; i++){
name.add(result.get(i).getName();} ` and you get all name columns data in name Arraylist.

Comment: @SarbjitSingh I already used same like your code. But my table have 10k rows. So I want to avoid 10k iteration.

Comment: There are no columns in Realm, so this question doesn't make sense. Relevant: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1210

Comment: If you want to avoid 10k iteration, then just receive your objects, don't project it down to a `List<String>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If we using Realm in Android, then which method do we have to use for fetching the data of only one column?

You can't, because Realm is an object store, it doesn't have concept of "columns".

---

> My problem:
>
> results.size()  > 10k. So I want to avoid 10k iteration
>
> ```
> for(i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){ 
> }
> ```

**Solution:** don't iterate?

```
 RealmResults<User> results = query.findAll();
 //List<String> name = new ArrayList<>(); 
 //for(i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){ 
 //     name.add(result.get(i).getName();
 //}
 return results;

 // ...
 String name = results.get(position).getName();
```

Comment: so what is the position is it the specific item ? 
 and i want to get all of them how ? i can't understand

Comment: If you want to get *all* of them, then you *do* have to iterate all the items. But I expected that you might want to show them in a RecyclerView instead, for example.

Comment: in my case it's different i want all ids of a table to get only these ids from another table 
like i have : class A : contain like some of class B ids 
 so i want to get all these ids from class A to get them from the class B

Comment: If the two classes are in the same Realm, then you could most likely just use `RealmList<B>`.

Comment: that's the final list i want is the RealmList<B> but based on the ids that exist on Class A

Answer (score 7):

Look at [queries](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries) section at the documentation:

> All fetches (including queries) are lazy in Realm, and the data is never copied.

This mean, that data of particular column (property) will be fetched when you call `getMyProperty()` method. Not after call of `finadAll()` method of `RealmQuery` object