# How to query to display only a single property from realm database with multiple properties?

Tags: android, realm

I intend to build an app that uses realm database. I have a table with 7 properties. The database model class is as below :

```
package com.abdkasim.Tremp130319.Realm;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

public class CasesModel extends RealmObject {

    String fileRef;
    String parties;
    String court;
    String courtAt;
    String caseNo;
    String caseStatus;
    String nextDate;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " \n CasesModel{" +
                "fileRef='" + fileRef + '\'' +
                ", parties='" + parties + '\'' +
                ", \n court='" + court + '\'' +
                ", courtAt='" + courtAt + '\'' +
                ", \n caseNo='" + caseNo + '\'' +
                ", caseStatus='" + caseStatus + '\'' +
                ", nextDate='" + nextDate + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

The problem is that there are instances where in an activity upon OnCreate I would like to display only 1 property and in other activity only to show 5 properties. How can we extract only 1 or 5 properties out of the total 7 and display them in a ListView.  I have found answers to display only 1 field that was asked 2 years ago and the codes no longer works in the android studio 3.3.2 I'm using now : [Fetch a single column from Realm Database (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640753/fetch-a-single-column-from-realm-database-android).   The given answer was the code below to fetch 1 property i.e name from the table and put it into an ArrayList but like i said it won't work in android studio now.

```
package com.abdkasim.Tremp130319.OtherPages;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

import com.abdkasim.Tremp130319.R;
import com.abdkasim.Tremp130319.Realm.CasesModel;

public class AllCasesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_cases);


        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);


        Realm realm;
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();


        RealmResults<CasesModel> results = query.findAll();

        return results;

        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
        for (i = 0; i<results.size; i++) {name.add(results.get(i).getName());
    }

}
```

So I'm very thankful if you could help me with the query syntax to display the 1 property immediately upon OnCreate as well as more than 1 property. I have created an adapter to show 5 properties mentioned above in a Cardview but do not know how to query realm database to show only the 5 fields I required and linked it to that adapter.

Your answer is very appreciated caused I'm stuck here quite a while.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some information in your question there - which field do you want to display, how do you want to display it?

The code you've taken from elsewhere isn't so much "won't work in android studio now" as is "not complete". It's mostly there.

As for 'only one property', well that doesn't make much difference to 'how you do it', the only difference is in how you make the list items. I'll show you the code for doing it for an arbitrary item from your class, but the code for any other property is the same, just swap in that property. Multiple properties can be achieved with string concatenation.

So, change your code to this.

```
public class AllCasesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_cases);


    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);


    Realm realm;
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();


    RealmResults<CasesModel> results = realm.where(CasesModel.class).findAll();


    ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CasesModel caseModel : results)
    {
      rows.add(caseModel.fileRef);

    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rows);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. I’ll apply your codes as soon as I can and get back to you with the outcome.

Comment: Hi Chris, there is an “unexpected token” sign for “case” and that the “fileRef” in case.fileRef is marked “unresolved”. I don’t know what are causing them.

Comment: Whoops, used a reserved word as a variable name - fixed above.

Comment: Its ok Chris, but now I got a new problem. It says that fileRef “is not public. Cannot be accessed from outside package”. I don’t understand this since we can refer to CasesModel here. How can we still refer to the class but not the properties.

Comment: Solved it Chris, by making the property public. Its working now. My next step to populate the selected properties to be displayed in a cardview and learn something about string concatenation. Thanks alot Chris. You’re Da Man.